# Listview- User Comments

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I am developing a functionality in my web app. Its a cooking community.The functionality is online discussion. The users can comment underneath a recipe. I used a listview control. I am able to retrieve the user name, using a nested query. Only one dataset object can be assigned to the DataSource property of the ListView control. I need both Username and Comment Value. The username is being diplayed. I am having problem with displaying the comment of that particular user.  but I need to display the comments of the users too. How do I achieve 
 code behind to display comments:

```
 public void dispComments()
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=FreedomKitchen;Uid=root;Password=;");
        con.Open();

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select Username from User_Details where User_ID in(select User_ID from Recipe_Comments)", con);
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "User_Comments");
        ListView1.DataSource = ds;
        ListView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }
```

List View Source Code:

```
             <ItemTemplate>

                 <div id="div123">
            <asp:Label ID="User" 
               runat="Server" 
               Text='<%#Eval("Username") %>'
        width="850"
        height="80"
         />
  <%--  <asp:Label ID="Comment" 
               runat="Server" 
               Text='<%#Eval("Comment") %>'
        width="850"
        height="80"
         />--%>
                 </div>

</ItemTemplate>
            <ItemSeparatorTemplate>

                <br />
            </ItemSeparatorTemplate>

        </asp:ListView>
```

Database: 
User_Details table

User_ID  //need to display this in a listview item
First_Name
Last_Name
Age
Gender
Country
About_User
Username
Password

User_Comments table

Recipe_ID
User_ID
Comment   //need to display this  a listview item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your database query to `join` both the comments and users table and select the result.

Un-comment the section inside Item Template for listview to show the comment also.

bind the selected result set to listview

EDIT:

You may need to include a `DateTime` column in your `User_Comments` table, as there may be multiple comments from one user which need to be displayed on the time order.

you can change your code like this, in `dispComments()` method

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT U.Username, R.Comment FROM Recipe_Comments R JOIN User_Details U ON R.User_ID = U. User_ID WHERE R.Recipe_ID = @RecipeID ORDER BY R.CommentDate DESC)", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecipeID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = value;
```

In your `ItemTemplate`

```
<ItemTemplate>
 <div id="div123">
   <asp:Label ID="User" runat="Server" Text='<%#Eval("Username") %>' width="850" height="80" />
   <asp:Label ID="Comment" runat="Server" Text='<%#Eval("Comment") %>' width="850" height="80" />
 </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```